# compiz, when I open windows, the title bar goes behind the menu bar

Tags: compiz

I'm using gnome classic (mate) and compiz, and when I restore a window, the titlebar is going out of workspace (Desktop) like this

[image]

In this case I try to open two applications, how all I open, the titlebar from that windows is undo menubar. Anyone know how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: By the way you can drag a window using Alt+left mouse click. You don't need to drag from the title bar. This should ease your life a bit until you resolve the issue. I think there's a value to offset a window from the top of the screen. You need to increase it, but I don't know how unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Finally!! i found a answer!!
Need the plugin **

> "Place Windows"

**
Thats plugin you can found in compiz config settings manager, only you need to do is enable it. if you do not have it installed:

```
sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager -y
ccsm
```